# Federal Pardon before being charged?

Tags: pardon

Is it possible to receive a presidential pardon before being charged (a "blanket" pardon or "pass")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [here is an example](https://www.fordlibrarymuseum.gov/library/speeches/740061.asp). Gerald Ford pardoned Richard Nixon:

> Now, THEREFORE, I, GERALD R. FORD, President of the United States,
> pursuant to the pardon power conferred upon me by Article II, Section
> 2, of the Constitution, have granted and by these presents do grant a
> full, free, and absolute pardon unto Richard Nixon *for all offenses
> against the United States which he, Richard Nixon, has committed or
> may have committed or taken part in during the period from January 20,
> 1969 through August 9,1974*.

But he was not charged with anything.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.   Gerald Ford's (in)famous pardon of President Nixon's role in the Watergate scandle is the most famous example.